# Webservice in .net

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

For the first time I try use a **webservice** in .net.

My code c# below, but I don't understand because the string **result** is not assigned.

If try delete the control in the rows **if (reader.HasRows)**, the string **result** is assigned.

How do I check the existence of the string email in the table Users?

Where is the mistake in my code behind?

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http:/.../ws")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class ws : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string es(string email)
    {
        string result;

        using (OdbcConnection conn =
            new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand())
            {
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.CommandText = "Select Email From tblUsers where email = ?;";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", email.ToString());
                command.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();

                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                try
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        result = "1";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.ToString();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off `email` is already a string, so you don't need to *.ToString()* it.

Second, (unless you are doing pre .NET 3.0) don't bother with classic ASMX web services and go with WCF.  There are plenty of resources on the web regarding WCF web services hosted on IIS

Third, you should probably implement a null check on your e-mail param before running anything `email != null`, or better yet, check for empty string as well `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)`, if using .NET 3.5 or earlier, use **IsNullOrEmpty**

Finally, to answer your question, to check if your first column (col 0), *Email* is null, you can do `reader.IsDBNull(0)`, but to test if it's empty string or not, you'll need to read in the value (assuming it's not null) then check, unless you do it through SQL (google it)

Also, use SqlCommand, SqlDataReader, and SqlConnection.  Unless you are interfacing with other database systems (other than SQL Server) and absolutely must use ODBC.